# writing a test for the method

Tags: java, unit-testing

Need to write a test for the following method

```
public static boolean isValidSsn(String aSsn) { //ssn = social security number
  if (aSsn.matches("\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}")) {   // Match found
  return true;
} 

// Not a valid number
return false;
}
```

I tried it, i know it is terribly wrong, but don`t know how to correct it.

```
public void testIsValidSsn() {
  String actual = "\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}";
  String exp = "123-45-6789";
  assertEquals(actual, exp);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Expected is the expected return value of the method and actual is what it actually returned. Call the method and store it within "actual" and compare to what you expected.

```
public void testIsValidSsn() {
  boolean actual = isValidSsn("123-45-6789");
  boolean exp = true;
  assertEquals(exp, actual);
}
```

Comment: Then the compiler cannot find the method isValidSSn

Comment: You need to instantiate the class your testing in your test class. (See my answer for example)

Comment: @BenjaminDale The method is static. I would just do a static import

Comment: Ahh yes, that would be best.

Answer (score 2):

Use parameterized unit test cases

```
@Test
@Parameters({"123-345-23,false","123-123-213-123,true"})
public void testIsValidSSN(String ssnValue, boolean expectedResult){
     boolean result = isValidSSN(ssnValue);
     assertEquals("Expected result did not match for SSN:" + ssnValue, expectedResult,result);
}
```

You will have to use [JUnitParams](https://code.google.com/p/junitparams/) library

### Advantages

- Reusability of test method. This is called Data Driven Unit Test.
- It addresses the limitation of JUnit of not being able to pass parameters as arguments to methods
- Easy to add new case, which gives you maintainability and readability

Answer (score 1):

Try this Regular Expression for your particular Sequence

```
^[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{4}$
```

this definitely helps you.

```
public class Sample 
{

        public static void main(String ar[])
{
      String aNumber= "254-58-3698";
       isValidNumber(aNumber);

}

public static Boolean isValidNumber(String aNumber)
{


      String pattern = "^[0-9]{3}\\-[0-9]{2}\\-[0-9]{4}$";

      // Create a Pattern object
      Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

      // Now create matcher object.
      Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
      if (m.find( )) {
         System.out.println("Number has Matched");  
return true;       
      } else {
         System.out.println("NO MATCH");
return false;
      }

}
}
```

output:

Number has Matched

Answer (score 1):

With testing, you want to test a call to the method:

```
public void shouldReturnTrueIfValidSSN() {
       // Given
       YourClass yourClass = new YourClass();   

       // When
       boolean result = yourClass.isValidSsn("123-456-789");

       // Then
       assertEquals(result, true);
}

public void shouldReturnFalseIfInvalidSSN() {
       // Given
       YourClass yourClass = new YourClass();   

       // When
       boolean result = yourClass.isValidSsn("yolo");

       // Then
       assertEquals(result, false);
}
```

You also want to make sure you cover all logic routes.